# Using the VBA 'CASE' statment to Replace several values in a String in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I know there's several posts which are similar to the one I am posting, and I've looked through them and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I've also checked out how to properly set up a CASE statement using VBA, but still can't find what I am doing wrong.

Basically, I have a user-entry form where the user enters a part number which looks something like this: 0 A1B2-3C-4D-5E6F. Once the user has added the record, the part number should scan the string for any " " or "-" and replace them with "", to look like this: A1B23C4D5E6F, and update the record in the table.

Here is the code I am using: (txtString as my field)

```
Public Function strReplace(txtString As Variant) As Variant

 Select Case txtString

        Case "-"
            strReplace = ""

        Case " "
            strReplace = ""

        Case Else
            strReplace = txtString

    End Select

End Function
```

I am still learning the ropes with VBA, but this compiles fine. Did I structure this code wrong, logically, for what I am trying to accomplish, or have I set up my code wrong? I appreciate all feedback and answers.

Thanks

*EDIT* This code is being called when frmAddString opens(within access' Macros & Code - Visual Basic - Form_frmAddString)

*EDIT2* I am trying this in a testing database which has the following:

tblTestingStrings

-Field1: StringID

-Field2: txtString

frmAddString(My code is located on this Pop up form which opens in Add)

-btnSaveandClose

-txtString

-StringID

*EDIT3* Code for frmAddString

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub btnSaveandClose_Click()

DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.Close

End Sub

Public Function strReplace(txtString As String) As String

 Select Case txtString

        Case "-"
          strReplace = ""

        Case " "
            strReplace = ""

        Case Else
            txtString = strReplace

    End Select

End Function
```

txtString being the place where the user types in a word.

Comment: You are comparing the full string, you need to compare the characters

Comment: @Barranka Would that not be what I want to do though? As in when a user enters a full string, look it over and replace what is needed?

Comment: @Dylan, the entry from the user does not equal `-` or ` `; your code is built as if it were one character.  You would need to split the entry into single characters and loop through that set, for example...not particularly efficient

Comment: Ok I understand what I am doing wrong. I am going to review this code and see how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually easer that what you're doing.

```
Public Function strReplace(txtString As Variant) As Variant
        strReplace = Replace(Replace(txtString, " ", ""), "-", "")
End Function
```

Comment: This looks good, but I would recommend using two lines instead of one for simple legibility.

Comment: I have a feeling that this also works, and when I tried it out by entering in 11-22-33, it still saved it in the table as 11-22-33. I am thinking it has something to do with the way my form is set up. I created a test database with the following: tblTestingStrings frmTestingStrings, frmAddString, where frmAddString simply adds prompts to add a new string. It also has a button with the DoCmd.Save and the DoCmd.Close.

Comment: @Dylan -- to prove this answer is indeed correct, paste this in your Immediate window and press Enter:  `?Replace(Replace("My Sam ple en-try", " ", ""), "-", "")`

Comment: @Dylan -- try changing `As Variant` to `As String`

Comment: Invalid Outside Procedure... I did it wrong, didn't I?

Comment: @Smandoli, I replaced the 'As Variant' with 'As String' it compiled great, but still saving the records with the "-".

Comment: @Dylan the function seems to be working. Revise your question to show us how this function is being called. It's possible you're not updating your form?

Comment: @David Zemens, I've revised my post to show exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @Dylan the function above is syntactically and semantically correct and so should work unless there is some other issue (as you are suspecting). Are you assigning the function output to the variable you are about to save to the table (you should be doing something like `myInputString = strReplace(myInputString): ...code to push it to the table...` or are you expecting the procedure to do that for you? Can you post your code for `DoCmd.Save`?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, edited to show all the code associated with frmAddString.

Comment: You can put the Key-word `Stop` as a single line within the Function. You can use this as a debugging tool - to see if your code is even calling and using the function.

Comment: @tbur, I took a different route as I was able to get it to do exactly what I want in  a query, so I just made the form off the query, and made the query update the records on the table where needed. Worked like a charm! I think the way I set up the form caused the issues. Thanks again for the answer!